# java with postgresql mistake with statement

Tags: java, postgresql, connection, database-connection

I have tried to getting result from db about has done query,db always get me "false" even when that has trued.

```
oldPassword = DBConfig.MD5(oldPassword);  //thase are me own classes
newPassword = DBConfig.MD5(newPassword);  

String updatePassword = "UPDATE login " + "SET password='"
+ newPassword + "'" + " WHERE password='" + oldPassword
+ "' and employee_id=" + userId + " ;";

Connection con = DBConfig.dbConfigure();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
boolean success = statement.execute(updatePassword);
LOGGER.info(success);
DBManager.close(con, statement, null); //I'm closing connectin,statmant and result set if that has
```

/************************************/
      DBConfig

```
    public static final String USER_NAME = "postgres";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String DB_NAME="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myTask";
public static final String DB_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";

    public static Connection dbConfigure() throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    String userName = USER_NAME;

    String dbPassword = PASSWORD;
    String dbName = DB_NAME;
    String dbDriver = DB_DRIVER;

    Class.forName(dbDriver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName, userName,
            dbPassword);
    return con;
}
```

Comment: IMO you should not use `password` as part of the query, instead retrieve the user password and do a match in server side i.e. in Java, then do a clean update. Also, use `PreparedStatement`s instead of plain `Statement`s to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Also, use `executeUpdate` method instead of plain `execute`.

Answer (score 1):

> db always get me "false" even when that has trued.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29):

The `execute` method returns **true** if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; **false if it is an update count** or there are no results

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [executeUpate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29). It is much more clear when you are doing INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. It returns number of rows effected by this query.